# Как завершать прокрутку лоудера по получению данных?

Tags: javascript, angular, асинхронность, loading

У меня ситуация, что и данные, и значение loading (true/false) я получаю через сервис. То есть код имеет примерно такой вид

```
this.data = this.service.getData();
this.loading= this.service.getLoading();
```

В data и loading приходит Observable, а при рендеринге данных используется пайп async. Проблема в том, что лоудер продолжает крутиться несколько секунд после того, как данные уже отрисовались. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Как вы отображаете данные?

Comment: ну значит loading заканчивается позже, чем data. А вот почему - надо смотреть весь ваш код.